# Can Cypress give me an error message when there has been an error?

Tags: cypress

I have the below snippet from my test case:

```
cy.get('item_here').should('not.exist');
```

Can cypress give me a custom error message when the "item_here" does exist?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain a log message on to the existing code, and it will only run if the element does not exist.

```js
cy.get('item_here').should('not.exist')
  .then(() => cy.log('no such element found'))  // Note; this is an additional log
```

Changing both "success" and "fail" messages is hard because Cypress likes to show the red `AssertionError` block when anything fails or an error is thrown.

You can use the `should()` callback version, but **please** use an `expect()` inside otherwise you do not have retry,

```js
  cy.get('item_here').should($el => {
    expect($el, 'Cannot be found').to.not.exist    // expect causes retry for 4 seconds
                                                   
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'Missing',
      message: 'Cannot be found'
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can throw your own errors in a callback function for [`.should()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Function).

```
cy.get(".does-not-exist")
  .should("not.exist")
  .then(($el) => {
    if ($el == null) {
      throw new Error("Item does not exist in DOM");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, does your statement essentially state "if this doesn't equal 1 then error?"

Comment: It essentially throws an error if there is not one element in the DOM that matches the selector. You can sub the `!==` with `>=` if you can expect at least one match.

Comment: If the element does not exist `cy.get('item_here')` will fail and the `.should()` will never run. You either need `.should('not.exist')` or an `expect` in the callback to modify the behaviour of `cy.get('item_here')`

Comment: Right. I was missing a step.Updated.